# Include all class files in Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, class, actionscript

I currently have all these files:

[image]

The problem is, none of the actionscript files are being included in `~shell.fla`. I [think I] can include all the files separately, but there are a TON.

It would take me all day to include each file separately. With that being the case, is there any shortcut to including those four folders in ~shell.fla? The files in the folders consist of primarily class files. I think these are called packages.

Comment: Well, the FLA is a project master file, which cannot include AS file bodies itself, but it includes references to them.

Answer (score 0):

In order to import all classes within a folder 'com' in your example:

```
import com.*;
```